# How to style tags selectively based on ancestor and attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web app that queries across multiple dictionaries which have their source in XML, and when an entry is found it displays the results under a heading for each dictionary styled as `<div id="DICTIONARY_eb" class="entry_box">`. Some of the dictionaries we're using have their own particular brand of XML, and we (and the maintainers of those dictionaries) would like to use their CSS for those entries, and a default CSS for other entries.

The current setup is that each dictionary entry is under a `div` tag with `id="DICTIONARY_eb"`. I'm not all too familiar with CSS, but I know that there is an *element element* selector; is there any way that this can be generalized to something like `div[id^=DICTIONARY] <sometag>` automatically? Or that I can define a subtree of CSS just for `div[id^=DICTIONARY]`? Or are we just going to have to define a different attribute/tag just for those dictionaries?

Thanks in advance either way!

Comment: you can use `div[id^="DICTIONARY"]` as you suggested. Here's a good article on attribute selectors http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: This is a great article, but I guess what I meant was is there a way I can define styles _for other tags_ under `div[id^=DICTIONARY]`? That is, given `div[id^=DICTIONARY]`, `p { color: ...; ...}`, etc. @myajouri

Comment: Spaces in CSS selector rules are for descendant elements.

Comment: @mrshanahan It's a little unclear what you're asking.. but the attribute selector is definitely the way to go.. you want something like this, right? http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/cDUGV/

Comment: @JoshC In that case, I apologize; that's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for! Again, I'm not too familiar with CSS, so I didn't know that that selector could apply to things that weren't just tags...thanks!

Comment: @JoshC If you want to, I'd be fine with that. But one more question - let's say I'm trying to use an entirely different stylesheet given `div[id^=DICTIONARY]`...is there any way to do that without prefixing every line in that sheet with `div[id^=DICTIONARY]`? I tried wrapping the entire stylesheet with `div[id=DICTIONARY_EB] { ... }`, but that didn't seem to do anything. (And yes, I did add a link to it in the HTML.) Thanks again!

Comment: You have specify `[id^=DICTIONARY]` before every element if you're using pure CSS. Although something like SASS (http://sass-lang.com/guide) will let you write that attribute selector once and nest everything else underneath.

Comment: @myajouri I had just heard about SASS the other day, but I didn't know what it was; this looks like exactly what I was hoping for with my second question. Thanks!